# <body> background img doesnt display in IE

Tags: css

I'm creating website and I ran into a problem with internet explorer (tested on ver. 8) where it doesn't display background image for

this is my code:

```
    body {
      background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(105,205,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 0 0;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
}
```

Any idea how to address this issue?

Comment: I updated the answer below, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle for the example. I don't know whether you want like this or not. But its working on IE as well. Check it. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/9hjrc/)

```
 body {
      background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(105,205,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#6BCEF9')"; /* IE8 */
      background-image: url(../images/bg.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(105,205,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 0 0;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
}
```

Here, I added the following line.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#6BCEF9')"; /* IE8 */
```

Check it and let me know. Thanks

Comment: This won't work on IE8 though, -ms-linear-gradient was aimed at targeting new IE releases. IE8 would have to be done w/ a filter but then you would lose the png as it doesn't support multiple bg images.

Comment: The filter isn't in the background declaration, will it work just like that? Also I've seen conflicts where the ms-filter option will overrite background declaration in IE9. I would also recommend moving the non vendor based definition to the top of the list. The only reason being that you'd want the vendor specific stuff to overshadow the non-vendor specific stuff until a true standard has been reached. I've seen an issue in IE9 where it identifies "linear-gradient" but doesn't know how to parse it and ends up not displaying a bg. -- might have been my specific setup at the time though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/iewebdevelopment/thread/4771f218-42fc-43b0-b0fd-bda98eef12ad

it talks about background images in IE8 conflicting with JS declarations. Not sure if that is the problem here. I know you shouldn't have a hasLayout issue here, but you might want to try putting a display:block; on the body. You should also make sure that the body is getting sized to the content inside of it (i.e. make sure floats are cleared etc -- although this would most likely be the culprit, only if your bgs were failing in most clients).

I like to put a border: 1px solid red; around stuff that I'm trying to position or debug something. Hope that helps some, sorry the answer isn't more complete.

also, another way to test this would be to add in IE conditional statements after css includes and then play around from there.